# Compiling Python to an exe

Tags: python-2.7, py2exe, distutils, pyinstaller

For the last week I have been struggling to compile a few python scripts and pyqt .ui file into an exe using pyinstaller/py2exe.  I am fairly new to programming and have never tried to package an application for distribution before.

So far I have succeeded in simplifying my gui application to one python script, but when I try to compile it, using either py2exe or pyinstall, I get the same error.

**With pyinstaller the error is:**

```
C:\Python27\pyinstaller-2.0>python utils\build.py costaharmplotter.spec
109 INFO: Testing for ability to set icons, version resources...
187 INFO: ... resource update available
203 INFO: UPX is not available.
2515 WARNING: library python%s%s required via ctypes not found
2625 INFO: checking Analysis
2625 INFO: building Analysis because out00-Analysis.toc non existent
2625 INFO: running Analysis out00-Analysis.toc
2625 INFO: Adding Microsoft.VC90.CRT to dependent assemblies of final executable

2640 INFO: Searching for assembly x86_Microsoft.VC90.CRT_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21
022.8_x-ww ...
2640 INFO: Found manifest C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\Manifests\x86_Microsoft.VC90.CRT_1fc
8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_x-ww_d08d0375.manifest
2656 INFO: Searching for file msvcr90.dll
2656 INFO: Found file C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\x86_Microsoft.VC90.CRT_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_
9.0.21022.8_x-ww_d08d0375\msvcr90.dll
2656 INFO: Searching for file msvcp90.dll
2656 INFO: Found file C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\x86_Microsoft.VC90.CRT_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_
9.0.21022.8_x-ww_d08d0375\msvcp90.dll
2656 INFO: Searching for file msvcm90.dll
2656 INFO: Found file C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\x86_Microsoft.VC90.CRT_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_
9.0.21022.8_x-ww_d08d0375\msvcm90.dll
2812 INFO: Analyzing C:\Python27\pyinstaller-2.0\support\_pyi_bootstrap.py
5484 WARNING: library python%s%s required via ctypes not found
5562 INFO: Analyzing C:\Python27\pyinstaller-2.0\PyInstaller\loader\archive.py
5875 INFO: Analyzing C:\Python27\pyinstaller-2.0\PyInstaller\loader\carchive.py
6297 WARNING: pywintypes is changing its name to pywintypes27
6797 INFO: Analyzing C:\Python27\pyinstaller-2.0\PyInstaller\loader\iu.py
6843 INFO: Analyzing costaharmplotter.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1844, in Tcl
    return Tk(screenName, baseName, className, useTk)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1745, in __init__
    self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, want
objects, useTk, sync, use)
_tkinter.TclError: Can't find a usable init.tcl in the following directories:
    {C:\Tcl\lib\tcl8.5} C:/Python27/lib/tcl8.5 C:/lib/tcl8.5 C:/lib/tcl8.5 C:/li
brary C:/library C:/tcl8.5.2/library C:/tcl8.5.2/library

C:/Tcl/lib/tcl8.5/init.tcl: version conflict for package "Tcl": have 8.5.2, need
 exactly 8.5.13
version conflict for package "Tcl": have 8.5.2, need exactly 8.5.13
    while executing
"package require -exact Tcl 8.5.13"
    (file "C:/Tcl/lib/tcl8.5/init.tcl" line 18)
    invoked from within
"source C:/Tcl/lib/tcl8.5/init.tcl"
    ("uplevel" body line 1)
    invoked from within
"uplevel #0 [list source $tclfile]"


This probably means that Tcl wasn't installed properly.
```

**I get a similar error with py2exe:**

```
C:\Documents and Settings\T53983\Desktop\HarmonicPlotterGUI>python setup.py py2e
xe
running py2exe
*** searching for required modules ***
*** parsing results ***
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 4, in <module>
    setup(data_files=['C:\\Python27\\tcl\\tcl8.5\\init.tcl'], console = ['costah
armplotter.py'])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\core.py", line 152, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py2exe\build_exe.py", line 243, in run
    self._run()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py2exe\build_exe.py", line 299, in _run
    py_files, extensions, builtins = self.parse_mf_results(mf)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py2exe\build_exe.py", line 1097, in parse_
mf_results
    tk = _tkinter.create()
_tkinter.TclError: Can't find a usable init.tcl in the following directories:
    {C:\Tcl\lib\tcl8.5} C:/Python27/lib/tcl8.5 C:/lib/tcl8.5 C:/lib/tcl8.5 C:/li
brary C:/library C:/tcl8.5.2/library C:/tcl8.5.2/library

C:/Tcl/lib/tcl8.5/init.tcl: version conflict for package "Tcl": have 8.5.2, need
 exactly 8.5.13
version conflict for package "Tcl": have 8.5.2, need exactly 8.5.13
    while executing
"package require -exact Tcl 8.5.13"
    (file "C:/Tcl/lib/tcl8.5/init.tcl" line 18)
    invoked from within
"source C:/Tcl/lib/tcl8.5/init.tcl"
    ("uplevel" body line 1)
    invoked from within
"uplevel #0 [list source $tclfile]"


This probably means that Tcl wasn't installed properly.
```

In my script, I use numpy, pyqtgraph.PlotWidget, pyqt4.QtCore and pyqt4.qtgui.

- Why is py2exe/pyinstaller looking for tcl if i didn't use tkinter?
- How do I go about excluding this package that is causing the problem? I already switched the tcl file from tcl 8.5.13 to tcl 8.5.2 but it still doesn't work.

Please do not link me to the py2exe/pyinstaller documentation, I have been reading it for the past few days and am still struggling to understand how all of the options work. I will post my setup.py file and spec file below for reference.

**setup.py file:**

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(console = ['costaharmplotter.py'])
```

**spec file:**

```
# -*- mode: python -*-
a = Analysis(['costaharmplotter.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Python27'],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=None)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure - [('Tkinter','C:\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk','PYMODULE')])
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          exclude_binaries=1,
          name=os.path.join('build\\pyi.win32\\costaharmplotter', 'costaharmplotter.exe'),
          debug=False,
          strip=None,
          upx=True,
          console=True )
coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               strip=None,
               upx=True,
               name=os.path.join('dist', 'costaharmplotter'))
```

Comment: I don't know why you switched tcl file form .13 to .2, while your program says it should be otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Last time I tried py2exe, I couldn't get it to work with anything newer than Python 2.6.  Looking at [Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/py2exe/files/py2exe/0.6.9/), and the old [update/news page](http://www.py2exe.org/old/), it looks like there still isn't support for anything newer than 2.6/2.7.

It looks like you're using 2.7, so try compiling with Python 2.6 instead.

Comment: Sorry, that's all I've got.